# Crash when app returns to foreground

Tags: ios, uitextfield, foreground

When one of my UITextField's has focus, and one leaves the app, when one comes back to the app, it reliably crashes with the stack trace below. I do not believe I have any specific code that runs when the app re-enters the foreground. Since none of the elements refer to my code, I don't know how to approach this bug. Many thanks in advance!!!

Sam

```
#0  0x01e2c09b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x011e744d in -[CALayer actionForKey:] ()
#2  0x011e27bd in actionForKey(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, NSString*) ()
#3  0x011e2735 in CA::Layer::begin_change(CA::Transaction*, unsigned int, objc_object*&) ()
#4  0x011e661f in CA::Layer::remove_sublayer(CA::Transaction*, CALayer*) ()
#5  0x011e6cd1 in CA::Layer::insert_sublayer(CA::Transaction*, CALayer*, unsigned long) ()
#6  0x011e7136 in -[CALayer addSublayer:] ()
#7  0x158fd468 in __49-[UIKeyboardSliceTransitionView initializeLayers]_block_invoke_0 ()
#8  0x02570e7c in __NSArrayEnumerate ()
#9  0x02570a16 in -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] ()
#10 0x02570925 in -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] ()
#11 0x158fd160 in -[UIKeyboardSliceTransitionView initializeLayers] ()
#12 0x158fd0b3 in -[UIKeyboardSliceTransitionView initWithFrame:] ()
#13 0x158fcf36 in -[TIRivenFactory transitionView] ()
#14 0x01605810 in -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar refreshForRivenPreferences] ()
#15 0x01606280 in -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar setKeyboardName:appearance:] ()
#16 0x0160ac8b in -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar showKeyboardType:appearance:orientation:withShift:] ()
#17 0x014e7c2a in -[UIKeyboardImpl updateLayout] ()
#18 0x014e4a8f in -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] ()
#19 0x014e44ae in -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:] ()
#20 0x017196d3 in -[UIKeyboardAutomatic willResume:] ()
#21 0x00cb74f9 in __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 ()
#22 0x025d10c5 in ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 ()
#23 0x0252befa in _CFXNotificationPost ()
#24 0x00bebbb2 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#25 0x013760ba in -[UIApplication _sendWillEnterForegroundCallbacks] ()
#26 0x01376588 in -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] ()
#27 0x01376e74 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
#28 0x01377beb in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#29 0x01369698 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#30 0x02097df9 in _PurpleEventCallback ()
#31 0x024faf3f in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#32 0x024fa96f in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#33 0x0251d734 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#34 0x0251cf44 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#35 0x0251ce1b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#36 0x020967e3 in GSEventRunModal ()
#37 0x02096668 in GSEventRun ()
#38 0x01366ffc in UIApplicationMain ()
#39 0x000028ad in main at /Users/pg/code/PortBuilder/PortBuilder/main.m:9
#40 0x000027d5 in start ()
```

Comment: Not too sure but I guess what I would do is just resign the first responder when the app dismisses.

Comment: Sam, see if you can create an app with just a single text field in it, and see if you can replicate the bug in that environment. Then you can work out a fix for it easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have one additional piece of info. The app crashes before **any** of the methods are called on my active view controller.

Evan, what makes you suggest to resign the first responder? Thanks.

Comment: One more piece of information. I enabled the Zombie objects and got this message: -[UIKeyboardSliceTransitionView actionForLayer:forKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x135ec110

What's this telling me?

Comment: Adding the screenshot from the Zombies Instrument: http://freeboundaries.com/Zombies.png

Comment: Did you ever get to spot the source of this crash?. I'm facing a stack trace similar to this one. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/a/7344196/354018 suggests. Did you check if you called any UIKit methods on another thread than the main thread?